# Toggle content on multiple rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple boxes, on multiple rows, on toggle the content should be placed underneath all boxes from the same row as clicked box, to the far left, not just underneath the clicked box. This is what I have:
https://codepen.io/tonyart/pen/VwwBzbP

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnmM2.png)

```js
$('.show').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.content').slideToggle();
  $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find('.content').slideUp('fast');
});
```

```css
.site-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 50px 20px 0;
}

.box-container {
  width: 250px;
}

.content {
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi tony will you include a screenshot of your desired output? I didn't quite catch "content should be placed underneath all boxes from the same row as clicked box, to the far left, not just underneath the clicked box"

Comment: not clear about what you want, you are confusing that box in second row moving while toggle content?

Comment: Hello, I attached a link to screenshot in description

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the position of the content to absolute. This will make the element align as you define using top, left, right, bottom, margin properties.

Once done, set the left property to 0 which will make it appear on the left most.

```css
.content {
  width:1200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

Note that, you will also need to make some space for the item as absolute positioning will not interact with any elements, it will overflow if no space is provided.

I've adjusted the .box margin. Added 20px top margin to it.

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid red;
  margin:20px 50px 20px 0;
}
```

Checkout the demo at: https://codepen.io/attila-antal/pen/dyyQmqg